# EditPad 7: Regular Expression for end of line?

Tags: regex, editpad

I'm using EditPad 7 to edit some text and using regular expressions within the find and replace. I am trying to find only words at the end of the line.

Ex:

```
Wrapper:H
Wrapper:H Binder:G
Wrapper:Honduras
```

I want to find the capital H on the first line not the second or third line.

Comment: The H$ works. Put it as an answer and ill accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Either `H$` or `H\Z` should work.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for more info

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether EditPad works in multi-line mode or not. If it does use this to find:

```
(Wrapper:)H$
```

and this to replace:

```
\1whateveryouwanttohaveinstead
```

Also, if you want to disregard additional whitespace between `H` and the end of the line (i.e if whitespace does not make **not** the end of the line), you can use this:

```
(Wrapper:)H\s*$
```

Comment: I don't think `(Wrapper:)H([\r\n])` works.  At least it doesn't when I test it.

Comment: Hm okay, but apparently EditPad works in multiline mode, so the first version should be all right. I'll just remove the second part.

Comment: EditPad is always in multiline mode (no reason not to be, for a text editor), and `H$` and `H([\r\n])` both match the first `H` in the OP's sample string when I try them.  Of course,  if the line separator happens to be CRLF (i.e., Windows mode), it only consumes the CR, not the LF.

Comment: @AlanMoore yeah I would have expected EditPad to be in multiline mode, but I couldn't test it, so I didn't assume it. And for `\r\n`, my code sample using `[\r\n]` put the group containing that character back in place, so it wouldn't have mattered if it was half a line break or a full one.